# iOS Certificates Expiry

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have an app which has an expired provisioning profile. It still seems to be in the app store so I assume you only have to update the provisioning profile when you next do an update (is this correct?).

The only problem I have is that the app uses push notifications and they seem to have stopped working, when the provisioning profile expires, do push notifications also stop working?

What would I renew every year? Would I have to create a new certificate, generate new provisioning profiles from that certificate and then recreate the push notification certificates every year?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 different certificates, one for your app and one for the push in your app.

> The Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) certificate, lasts for one
>   year and must be 
>       renewed annually. You can create a new certificate or renew your older certificate.
>       Their expiry is not linked to the provisioning profiles that [indirectly] reference them.

Here is a tutorial to help you renewing you certificate : [how to renew push certificate](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-renew-your-apple-push-notification-push-ssl-certificate/)

Comment: At the moment, our provisioning profile has expired but our APNS certificate has not. The apps when downloaded from the app store however do not send their unique ID to our online push database any more like they used to. Could this be down to the expired provisioning profile?

Comment: I didn't encounter this problem but the renewing the APNS could be a solution, I can't be sure. How old is your APNS ?

Comment: The APNS is not too old, maybe 6 months but it doesn't show as expired etc.

Comment: The APNS may not be the source so... I don't know why you can't receive new ID sorry.

Comment: Can you renew an APNS certificate without having to update the provisioning profiles? So can we update the certificate in developer.apple.com and then it will continue working or will we once a year have to update the app?

Comment: You can renew your APNS without making update of your app, it is independent of you provisioning profiles.

Comment: So we would just create the new certificates online and then create the pem file for our push notification code to send using and that would be it done? We wouldn't have to do anything with the provisioning profiles?